# Generate Valid Random Faker Values in Go

Tags: validation, go, testing

I am using Validator package. I have the next Struct:

```
type User struct {
    Name       string `validate:"required"`
    Email      string `validate:"required,email"`
    CreditCard string `validate:"credit_card"`
    Password   string `validate:"min=8,max=255"`
}
```

What can I do to generate valid random values for thats fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [faker](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bxcodec/faker/v3) package. It has functions like `FirstName()`, `Email()`, `CCNumber()`. You can also use tags ([one](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bxcodec/faker/v3#example-package-WithTags), [two](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bxcodec/faker/v3#example-package-WithTagsLengthAndBoundary)) with this package in your struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing tests, you can use [Fuzzing](https://go.dev/doc/fuzz/) (implemented in Go 1.18).

Would look like this:

```golang
import "testing"

func TestHello(f *testing.F) {
    // Add your seeds here
    f.add("John", "john@test.com", "1234-5678-1234-5678", "@HelloWorld123")
    
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, name, email, creditCard, pass string)  {
        // Write your test here
    }))
}
```

Then run:

```bash
$ go test -fuzz
```